# How do I calculate the value of this series for $a = 1/3?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

I want to calculate the following series at $a = 1/3$

$\\ 1 + \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a(a-1)\cdots(a-n+1)}{n!}\frac{1}{2^{n}}$

I have no clue. I wanted to use the geometric series but didn't know how to simplify the term.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: If nothing else, it's not difficult to compute this numerically.  Then play with it a bit to try to identify the apparent limit.  It's often easier to prove a result you've guessed at numerically than it is to compute something blindly.

Comment: I tried this but I think I'm on the wrong path. This was an old exam question, worth 2 points so it should be not too time-consuming. :( The solution is (3/2)^(1/3) but I don't know how they got this

Comment: Entertainingly, While the answer certainly is $\sqrt[3] {1.5}=1.144714243$, this is surprisingly close to $\ln {\pi}=1.144729886$

Answer (score 3):

Observe that if $a \in \mathbb{N}\cup\left\{0\right\}$, $$\frac{a(a-1)\dotsm(a-n+1)}{n!} = \frac{a(a-1)\dotsm(a-n+1)(a-n)\dots1}{n!(a-n)!} = \frac{a!}{n!(a-n)!} = \binom{a}{n},$$ or if $a$ isn't a non-negative integer, we just have $$\binom{a}{n} := \frac{a(a-1)\dotsm(a-n+1)}{n!}$$ by definition. (Note that the empty product here is taken to be $1$, so $\binom{a}{0} = 1$ for all $a$, consistently between both definitions.)

Hence, in either case, by the generalised binomial theorem (since $\left\lvert\frac{1}{2}\right\rvert < 1$), your sum is $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{a}{n}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n = \left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)^a = \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^a.$$

Comment: Is $~\displaystyle \binom{1/3}{0}~$ defined to be $~1~?$

Comment: Yes, $\binom{x}{0}$ is defined to be $1$ for all $x$ - which of course makes sense, given that the factorial definition gives $1$ when $x$ is an integer. When $x$ isn't an integer, $\binom{x}{n}$ is defined as precisely the expression you started with, and the empty product is taken to equal $1$ by convention. I've slightly edited my answer to discuss this.